# Postbuild for pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow

I am currently working with a pipeline in Jenkins and I was wondering if there was any way to call a "post-pipeline" script, much like the post-build plugins made for freestyle. I want it to run and actually pass whether the pipeline failed or passed to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `catchError` step, or various more explicit idioms mentioned in that step’s documentation.